# How to differentiate between char literal and unsigned int as a parameter for a constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, char, unsigned

My Code has 2 different constructors, one with just an unsigned as a parameter and another one with a char and an unsigned, where the unsigned has a default value.

```
Myclass::Myclass(unsigned);
Myclass::Myclass(const char, unsigned = 1);
```

The problem ist that when I try the following:

```
Myclass a = 'A';
```

the constructor with only the unsigned as parameter is called(in this example with 65)

How can i have the second constructor be called in this case?
I also dont want values from 0-255 to only be interpreted as Ascii values.

EDIT:

Example code that displays error:

Header:

```
#ifndef Myclass_H_
#define Myclass_H_

class Myclass {
public:
    Myclass(unsigned int = 10);
    Myclass(const char*);
    Myclass(char , unsigned int= 10);
    Myclass(const Myclass&);
    virtual ~Myclass();
};

#endif /* Myclass_H_ */
```

Class body:

```
#include "Myclass.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Myclass::Myclass(unsigned int)
{
    cout << "unsigned" << endl;
}
Myclass::Myclass(const char*)
{
    cout << "pointer" << endl;
}
Myclass::Myclass(char , unsigned int)
{
    cout << "char" << endl;
}
Myclass::Myclass(const Myclass&)
{
    cout << "copy" << endl;
}
Myclass::~Myclass(){}

int main()
{
    Myclass a = 'A';
    return 0;
}
```

displays "unsigned" in console.

Comment: You should make the constructors explicit, to avoid semantic complications.

Comment: I think the answer to the question is: get a working C++ compiler! The second overload is clearly better. If the compiler chooses the `unsigned` overload when converting from a character literal it is wrong. Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) showing the problem?

Comment: Re. the "edit", of course `'A'` does not match `(char , unsigned int)` . You originally claimed the second parameter had a default value.

Comment: my bad didnt copy the default value.

Comment: You still don't have the default value in the header. Is that intentional

Comment: Also `Myclass::Myclass(const char, unsigned = 1);` is illegal code.  If this is a declaration it must be inside the class definition and not have `Myclass::` on the front.  If outside the class definition, it must have a function body.

Comment: g++ 4.8.1 selects the `char` constructor for the code you have posted. Howver, if `Myclass a = 'A';` were in a different source file from the code`Myclass::Myclass(char, unsigned int = 10) { ... }`, it would select the `unsigned` constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to duplicate the problem you claim. I did a quick check with the following test code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    foo(const char, unsigned = 1) { std::cout << "Foo(char, unsigned)"; }
    foo(unsigned) {
        std::cout << "Foo(unsigned)";
    }
};

int main() {
    foo f = 'A';
}
```

...and with the compilers I have handy (VC++ 2013, VC++ 2015, g++ 4.8, g++5.2), `foo(char, unsigned)` is always the one that's chosen (which is as I'd expect).

What compiler are you using that selects the other overload for this input? I'd expect this from truly ancient compilers (that followed the C rule, where a character literal has type `int` rather than type `char`) but those have been obsolete for decades.

Comment: Is MSVC++6.0 still the most popular environment around...?

Comment: @DietmarKühl: If memory serves, even it got this right. You'd have to go back to something like MSVC++ 4.x (or maybe even 2.x) to get this one wrong.

Comment: I am using mingw on windows, so a port of gcc version 4.8.1.

Comment: @JDNoodle: what version (use `gcc -v` to find out)? If it says something smaller than 4.9.* I'd recommend updating. The oldest gcc I have access to right now (3.4.6 from 2006, i.e., not quite as old as Jerry demands) chooses the correct overload.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `unsigned` constructor `explicit`, something like:

```
Myclass {
    explicit Myclass (unsigned);
    // ...
}
```